# Побитовое отрицание в unsigned long long

Tags: c++, c

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему если при безнаковом типе данных unsigned long long присвоить ~0 (unsigned long long переменная = ~0), то получается число 18446744073709551615. Почему выводится именно это число, и как именно в данном случае работает побитовое отрицание?

Answer (score 2):

```
~0000...0000 = 1111...1111 = 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615
     64 нуля       64 единицы
```

Comment: Вы напутали, `0` - это `int`, биты `unsigned long long` тут не инвертируются.

Comment: Весь выхлоп компилятора - `mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], -1`

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned long long переменная = ~0;` происходит не присваивание, а инициализация с использованием синтаксиса *copy-initialization*. Причем с правой стороны стоит выражение с типом `int`, а не `unsigned long long`. Целочисленный литерал `0` имеет тип `int`. Затем к нему применяется оператор bitwise complement, обращающий все биты из 0 в 1, в результате получается значение `-1` (`2^32 - 1`, 32 единичных бита), так как сейчас стандарт требует чтобы для отрицательных целых чисел использовалась форма с дополнением двойки (*two’s complement*). Затем происходит преобразование этого числа с одновременным переходом от 32 бит до 64 бит и от знакового типа до беззнакового типа. Такое преобразование происходит за счет вычисления нового значения, как исходного значения, взятого по модулю 2 в степени N, где N - количество битов в новом значении.

> 7.3.8 Integral conversions **[conv.integral]**
> ...
> 3 Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2N, where N is the width of the destination type.

`2^64 - 1`, 64 единичных бита, что есть `18446744073709551615`

Comment: `вычисления нового значения, как исходного значения, взятого по модулю 2 в степени N, где N - количество битов в новом значении` это звучит как-то сомнительно при расширении числа

Comment: @MBo Звучит действительно сомнительно, поэтому я привел соотв. цитату из стандарта.

Comment: На мой взгляд, вы описываете integral promotion, а к какому случаю применяется пункт 3 -не очень ясно

Comment: @MBo Нет, я описываю именно Integral conversions. integral promotion описываются в разделе **[conv.prom]**. Пункт 3 применяется к случаю из вопроса - когда int преобразуется в ull.

Comment: @user7860670, если говорит проще,, то сначала знаковое преобразуется к нужному размеру (при этом знаковый бит расширяется). Затем пишем этот результат в память, содержимое которой трактуется как беззнаковое (сама запись физически может и не проводиться (выбрасывается оптимизатором) если ее результат используется далее и уже хранится в регистре)

Comment: @avp Вот это `сначала знаковое преобразуется к нужному размеру` для меня выглядит логично, а `преобразование этого числа с одновременным переходом от 32 бит до 64 бит и от знакового типа до беззнакового типа` - неоднозначно.